# How to display data from Mob-x store on click

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react-form

I have this component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './cardCheck.css';

@inject('auto')
@observer
class CardCheck extends Component {
  render() {
    const { auto } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="newsletter-container">
          <h1>Enter the ID of your card:</h1>
          <div className="center">
            <input type="number" />
            <input type="submit" value="Check" onClick={event => {displayInfo}} />
          </div>
          <div className="results"></div>
        </div>
        <h1>Offers:</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

CardCheck.propTypes = {
  auto: PropTypes.shape({
    carCount: PropTypes.number
  })
};

CardCheck.wrappedComponent.defaultProps = {
  auto: autoPropTypeDefaults
};

export default CardCheck;
```

I want to make so that when someone clicks the input with value Check the div below with the className of results to be populated with my data from the store:

```
import { observable, action, computed } from 'mobx';

class Auto {
  @observable
  auto = [
    {
      name: 'Shop1'
    },
    {
      name: 'Shop2'
    }
  ];

  @action
  displayInfo() {

  }

}

export { Auto };
```

I tried to make the displayInfo function iterate through the array with objects with a map from loadash but it didn't work, it did not displayed the data inside the div, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an observable field on your `CardCheck` component that you toggle with the `onClick` event handler, and when the field is `true` you can display all entries in the `auto` array.

**Example**

```
class CardCheck extends Component {
  @observable
  checked = false;

  onClick = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.checked = !this.checked;
  };

  render() {
    const { auto } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="newsletter-container">
          <h1>Enter the ID of your card:</h1>
          <div className="center">
            <input type="number" />
            <input type="submit" value="Check" onClick={this.onClick} />
          </div>
          <div className="results">
            {this.checked &&
              auto.auto.map((a, index) => <div key={index}>{a.name}</div>)}
          </div>
        </div>
        <h1>Offers:</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried but it blows up with this error: 25:91  error  Do not use Array index in keys  react/no-array-index-key

Comment: @PeterJohnson Alright. That looks like a linter error, not a MobX error. If you know that the `auto` names will be unique, you can use `key={a.name}` instead, or you could add a unique `id` property to your elements in the `auto` array and use that as `key`.